# Overriding *_attributes= method rails with nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, overriding, nested-attributes

For some reason too long to explain I need to override the `*_attributes=(attributes)` method of my model, which accepts nested attributes for another model. As an example, here are my models:

```
class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

    def company_attributes=(attributes)
        ...
    end
end
```

First I started creating a new company every time this method was called (by substituting `...` with `self.company = Company.new(attributes)`). Needless to say it would go and save a new company to the database.

When I found out it was doing such a thing, I edited this method to the following:

```
def company_attributes=(attributes)
    self.company.nil? ? self.company = Company.new : self.company.assign_attributes(attributes)
end
```

which seemed to be the right way to go (it would only create a new object if it was nil, otherwise it would just assign the changed attributes). However, whereas for new experiences it was saving the newly created company to the database, when editing an experience it would change the company's attributes just after the method's single line, but it would not save it to the database.

**Question 1:** how do the generated `*_attributes=(attributes)` methods work?

**Question 2:** how should I change my `company_attributes=(attributes)` method in order to achieve my goal: create a new company when creating a new experience and editing the company's attributes when editing the experience.

Thanks

Comment: Company.new(attributes) was saving to the database? I think only Company.create(attributes) would save